# Unsubscribing events in WPF Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, dispose

I have a custom control, a range slider, which is used in one of my views.

The constructor looks like this:

```
        EventHandler ReCalculateWidthsHandler;
        public RangeSlider()
        {
            ReCalculateWidthsHandler = OnReCalculateWidths;
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ActualWidthProperty, typeof(RangeSlider)).
                AddValueChanged(this, ReCalculateWidthsHandler);
        }
```

I do not know when/how I can unscubscribe that event handler.  There is no Dispose method in Control.  Is there any way I can be notified that the control is being disposed/removed so that I can unsubscribe any subscribed events?

This can be a more general question: Given a custom control that extends Control, how can you tell when it is disposed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you should use [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata.aspx) to add change handler for dependency property. Unfortunately it doesn't work for read only properties. That's why you use property descriptor I think. You know this way is too complicated because AddValueChanged stores static strong reference which cause memory leak. I think you should call ReCalculateWidthsHandler from the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) event instead of subscribing to property descriptor.

Comment: If I changed it to subscribe regularly to the SizeChanged event, where would I unsubscribe that event when the control is disposed?  Wouldn't I be left with a memory leak if I didn't unsubscribe?

Comment: No. There will be no external reference if you subscribe handler to an event of the same instance.

Comment: Ah, yes.  That slipped my mind.  Let's say that another control was passed in to my custom control and my custom control subscribed to one of its events, something like otherControl.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler.  When would my custom control unsubscribe from that event so that a reference to otherControl is not held on to?

Comment: There is no a single specific point to unsubcribe in WPF. When I need to reference another control, I declare dependency property and use Binding. Dependency property gives you change notification where you can manage subscription while Binding holds a weak reference and reflects visual tree changes. The last one allows you to react when reference become invalid due to tree change and to unsubscribe from events (in property change handler).